# async.waterfall not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using `async.waterfall` for the first time and I'm running into some trouble.

Here are the two functions I'm trying to call:

```
function generateImageURL(data, callback){
   // ... xhr stuff
    xhr.onload = function () {
        callback(data, JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).data.link);
    }
  // ... more xhr stuff
    xhr.send(fd);
}
```

and

```
function generateCoordinates(data, url, callback){
    console.log("CALLED"); // never gets called
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(p){
        data.image_url = url;
        data.coordinates = [p.coordinates.longitude, p.coordinates.latitude];
        callback(data);
    });
}
```

My waterfall function looks like this:

```
 async.waterfall([
        generateImageURL.bind(this, data),
        generateCoordinates
    ], function(err, result){

    });
```

I want to pass in `data` from the outer scope into `generateImageURL` and then pass that data on towards `generateCoordinates` along with the `url`. The `callback` from `generateCoordinates` should call the anonymous function.

My issue is that `generateCoordinates` is never being called. Even though I call it within `generateImageURL`.

Comment: You need to put the code for both functions

Comment: The basic idea is to invoke the callback functions in the all functions (`generateImageURL`, `generateImageURL`). When the last function calls its callback, the last function you pass to `waterfall` will be invoked.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I believe I am calling the callbacks. I've updated my question with the function bodies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.waterfall):

> Each function is passed a callback(err, result1, result2, ...) it must call on completion. The first argument is an error (which can be null) and any further arguments will be passed as arguments in order to the next task.

and

> If any of the tasks pass an error to their own callback, the next function is not executed.

Your callback is `callback(data, JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).data.link);`, you pass `data` as the `err` argument, therefore it's interpreted as an error and your next function is not called. You should see it if you `console.log(err)` in your final callback.

Call your callback as `callback(null, data, JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).data.link);`

Comment: Thanks, this helps clarify things a lot! The reason I was confused initially is because none of the functions in the chain, except for the last one have an `err` parameter. How is this passed in implicitly?

Comment: The point is that as soon as you pass an error to any of the callbacks, the chain breaks and the main callback is immediately executed. The error is not passed along the chain, but only handled at the level of the main callback, that's why only the main callback has an err parameter.